# How do I verify an association based off a column in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Say I have an `assets` model that contains two columns:

```
Assets
    ownership:string
    lease_id:integer   # My Lease Object
```

So `ownership` can either be "OWN" or "LEASE".

Now, I only want to allow a `lease_id` if ownership is `LEASE` and if ownership happens to be `LEASE` then I want to require a lease object.

How can this be done in Rails 3.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add optional validations based on a method which returns true/false. Keep in mind that this will only enforce that a `lease_id` is present when `ownership == "LEASE"`. This will not restrict a `lease_id` from being added in any case.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :lease_id, presence: { :if => :lease? }

  def lease?
    self.ownership == "LEASE"
  end
end
```

If you want to restrict a `lease_id` altogether, you can use a callback to remove the property before the object is saved to the DB.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :restrict_lease_id

  def restrict_lease_id
    lease_id = nil if self.ownership == "LEASE"
  end
end
```